# Problem with vba update query with inner join

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Inner join update query has no errors but doesn't update. I've tried the many solutions offered but still doesn't work! 
I need to update status field from all records from CN99s  to [Report_LEC].[STATUSD]

```sql
UPDATE Report_LEC INNER JOIN CN99s ON Report_LEC.network = CN99s.nwk SET 
[Report_LEC].[STATUS] = CN99s.nwk_status;
```

If I do it manually via code it works!But very slow!

```vb
statstr = rs![nwk_status]
netstr = rs!nwk
CAPSQL = "UPDATE Report_LEC " & "SET status = '" & statstr & "' " & "WHERE NETWORK =" & netstr

DoCmd.RunSQL (CAPSQL)
```

There are 357216 records in CN99s and  13756 records in Report_LEC.

Thanks

Pete

Comment: *doesn't work* isn't very helpful. What exactly happens? [ask]

Comment: No update takes place yet no error is indicated! I see the query bar advance and it shows the fields when it is completed but nothing is updated!

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem which turned out to be my own stupidity!  I was hitting datasheet view and seeing the query bar show up and advance, I thought it was actually doing the update,
but you have to save a RUN the query for it to work! 
Hadn't touched access in a few months and got fooled!

Pete